# Write a price caption under each day with Flatpickr?

Tags: flatpickr

What I want to do is something like what I have shown in the picture below. I've been trying for a few days to do this but couldn't figure it out. I would like help from anyone who has done this before or can solve the problem.

[image]

my flatpickr javascript code:

```
$('.flatpickr4').flatpickr({
    beforeDayCreate: function(dayElem, dObj) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            if (dObj.format('Y-m-d') === dates[i]) {
                dayElem.innerHTML += '<div class="price-label">' + prices[i] + ' TRY</div>';
            }
        }
    },
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
    enable: dates,
    minDate: "{{ now()->format('Y-m-d') }}",
    inline: true,
    locale: turkish
});
```

Comment: `minDate: "today" `

Comment: What erorr are you getting

Comment: Prices never come. I couldn't find any documentation or tutorial on how to make this image.

Comment: I still haven't been able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event for flatpickr called 'beforeDayCreate'. There is 'onDayCreate'. Here is the full list of options:  https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr/blob/master/src/types/options.ts#L19